# Insert space in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is just a simple question here.
I want to insert a space between a bootstrap button and a text.

```
<%- @cv.each do |p| -%>
    <%- if !p.personal.nil? %>
      <div id="cv_<%= p.id %>">
          <h2><%= p.nom %>
           **** SPACE HERE ****
          <%= link_to 'edit', cvsindex2_path(p), :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
          <%= link_to 'delete', p, remote: true, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %></br>
          </h2>
      </div>
  <%- end %>
<%- end -%>
```

My CSS for h2 is :

```
h2 {
   text-align: center;
}
```

I have try to put `<%= " " %>` or `<%= "#{p.nom}    " %>` but that doesn't work
How I can do that.

Comment: you need 1 visual space, or break line ?

Comment: just visual space between the two entities !

Comment: When you add content at next line, `erb` will add visual space, people have other problems, how to remove empty space

Comment: Is `&nbsp;` work here?

Comment: There is already whitespace at the location you've indicated.

Comment: I want to keep them on the same line. But thank you `&nbsp;` work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use html for spacing, use css:

```
<h2>
  <span><%= p.nom %></span>
  <%= link_to 'edit', cvsindex2_path(p), :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', p, remote: true, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %></br>
</h2>

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  span {
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `&nbsp;` (stands for Non-Breaking SPace) between the two elements that you want to separate.

Yes, positioning should typically be added in CSS. But this is a single, standard-sized text space `" "`. It's content, not presentation. There's no reason to hack together a CSS solution that might not scale properly to different screens without extra work, when browsers already know how to render a single space character in a consistent way.